# Error: "No space left on device" when trying to install bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, virtualbox, rbenv

I'm using a virtual box setup (vagrant and virtualbox) recommended by TeamTreehouse.com([the setup](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/installing-a-ruby-development-environment/installing-a-ruby-development-environment/installing-the-treehouse-vm-on-windows)) and every time I try to start a new project or install a new gem I get the following errors:

`Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device - /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.1`

or

```
Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device - /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/cache/rails_serve_static_assets-0.0.2.gem
```

or when i cd into the virtual box i'll get

```
/home/treehouse/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 151: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on
 device
```

I have a few projects now and I guess I'm using up too much space somewhere but I have no idea how the virtual box stuff works. It runs Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-41-generic i686). Here is my `df -h` log

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/treehouse--vg-root  7.0G  4.8G  2.0G  72% /
udev                            240M  4.0K  240M   1% /dev
tmpfs                            50M  292K   50M   1% /run
none                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            248M     0  248M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                       228M  184M   32M  86% /boot
/vagrant                        187G   97G   90G  52% /vagrant
/home/treehouse/projects        187G   97G   90G  52% /home/treehouse/projects
```

I don't know how to get to the /dev/sda1 directory to find stuff to delete let alone know what is okay to delete. I deleted a couple of practice projects but I am still getting the same errors.

Here is a gist of when I turn on the vm https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eab0855295011f5d2ddf

This is a `dir` of .rbenv gems, it's pretty long and i'm not sure how I'm supposed to manage it without breaking things.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2017be4b947b44b08ce1

I could use some guidance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is very strange since from what you show it is trying to write to the /home/treehouse/ directory, which seems to be mapped to your /vagrant folder so it is actually on your host machine.  In fact, it seems to have 90 gigs of space free so that should not be the problem.

You even seem to still have 2 gigs on / directory.  And your ownership and permissions deem correct.

I looked around, and it was suggested that maybe your problem is not space, but that all your inodes are used up?  Try doing:

```
df -i
```

And see what comes out.  Check out [this](http://superrb.com/blog/2011/10/25/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-is-it-a-lie-or-have-i-run-out-of-inodes) blog post.  Might help you out.

(Edit: Original blog post now links to 404 page. [Internet archive link here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150707135333/http://www.superrb.com/blog/2011/10/25/ubuntu-no-space-left-on-device-is-it-a-lie-or-have-i-run-out-of-inodes).)

Comment: I don't have access to my computer for a few more days but I truly appreciate your help Noel, thank you. I'll get back to you with how everything works out

Comment: you were right about the inodes, I do have one at 100%. It looks like `/users/src` is the issue with 315805 files. It looks like I have some old kernel headers that might need deleting. How do I know which is safe to remove tho? Here is a gist of them https://gist.github.com/anonymous/456d5e39ea3b8300725b I read online that as long as you don't delete the latest ones everything should be ok